# error: C2065: 'GL_GEOMETRY_SHADER': undeclared identifier

Tags: qt, opengl-es

I'm getting this error while trying to build an application with QtCreator with Qt 5.11 and **MSVC 2017** compiler installed by [Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2017](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/community/):

> C:\Users\IEUser\go\src\company\3dpe\3dpe-materials.cpp:190: error:
>   C2065: 'GL_GEOMETRY_SHADER': undeclared identifier

The error happens at the **second line** of code below, notice that the 1st line and 3rd line are OK, only 2nd line is bad:

```
data[renderer]->vtxShd = addShaderToProgram(vertexShaderSource, GL_VERTEX_SHADER, data[renderer]->shdPrg, renderer);
data[renderer]->geoShd = addShaderToProgram(geometryShaderSource, GL_GEOMETRY_SHADER, data[renderer]->shdPrg, renderer);
data[renderer]->frgShd = addShaderToProgram(fragmentShaderSource, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, data[renderer]->shdPrg, renderer);
```

The error screen-shot is show below:

[image: GL_GEOMETRY_SHADER error screen-shot]

---

The error happens because the `GL_GEOMETRY_SHADER` is not defined in following header files:

`gl3.h` header file:

```
    Directory: C:\Qt\Qt5.11.0\5.11.0\winrt_x64_msvc2017\include\QtANGLE\GLES3


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----        5/14/2018  11:28 PM          83875 gl3.h
```

`gl2.h` header file:

```
    Directory: C:\Qt\Qt5.11.0\5.11.0\winrt_x64_msvc2017\include\QtANGLE\GLES2


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----        5/14/2018  11:28 PM          44659 gl2.h
```

---

The error does **NOT** happen when building with **MinGW** compiler.

---

I couldn't figure out the solution so far, just thought someone would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Geometry shaders are **not** supported in OpenGL ES 3.0. See [OpenGL ES Shading Language 3.00 Specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/es/3.0/GLSL_ES_Specification_3.00.pdf)

But Geometry shaders are supported since OpenGL ES 3.2. See. [OpenGL ES Shading Language 3.20 Specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/es/3.2/GLSL_ES_Specification_3.20.pdf)

See further [Khronos OpenGL ES Registry](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/index_es.php).

Comment: @user3405291 3.2 is the most recent OpenGL ES version. But it depends on your hardware and driver, whether it is supported.